# Is there an alternative method to achieve a similar functionality as showDirectoryPicker() in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, api, file, firefox, download

Is there an alternative to using showDirectoryPicker() in Firefox for creating folders and saving files in a user's file system using the File System Access API? Alternatively, do you know when Firefox plans to support showDirectoryPicker()?

I used showDirectoryPicker() to implement a download manager, but it doesn't work with firefox.

Comment: [`showDirectoryPicker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/window/showdirectorypicker) is an experimental feature and is only implemented by Chrome. It's not expected that this feature will be available in other browsers in near future.

Comment: Will be avail, in all chromiun based now, and in Safari tech preview version. As in caniuse.com

Comment: There is an answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77132443/5581893