# Any workarounds for using window.showDirectoryPicker in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser

The API window.showDirectoryPicker works fine on all Chromium based browsers.

However, Firefox has no such API yet. Any workarounds?

It's weird that Firefox has APIs for file and directory handles but not the picker dialogues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to use the `showDirectoryPicker` ponyfill from https://github.com/use-strict/file-system-access/tree/master.

Example in `index.html` file that works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onClick="showPicker()">Click mee</button>
        <script type="module">
            import { showDirectoryPicker } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/file-system-access/lib/es2018.js';
            const showPicker = async () => {
                try {
                    const handle = await showDirectoryPicker();
                    console.log(handle);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            };
            window.showPicker = showPicker;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```